# MongoDB: Find an element in a document that contains an object with a subobject with an array

Tags: mongodb

I'm getting puzzled more and more discovering how mongodb is overcomplicated and bad designed in the query writing, anyway I have this kind of document in a db with thousand of records:

```
db.messages.aggregate([{$limit: 1}]).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4f16fc97d1e2d32371003f42"),
        "body" : "Hey Gillette,\n\nThe heat rate is going to depend on the type of fuel and the construction \ndate of the unit.  Unfortunately, most of that info is proprietary.  \n\nChris Gaskill is the head of our fundamentals group and he might be able to \nsupply you with some of the guidelines.\n\n-Bass\n\n\n   \n\tEnron North America Corp.\n\t\n\tFrom:  Lisa Gillette                           04/05/2001 02:31 PM\n\t\n\nTo: Eric Bass/HOU/ECT@ECT\ncc:  \nSubject: Power Generation Question\n\nHey Bass,\n\nI have a question and I am hoping you can help me.  I am wanting to compile a \nlist of all the different types of power plants and their respective heat \nrates to determine some sort of generation ratio.\n\ni.e. Coal  4 mmbtu = 1 MW\n Simple Cycle 11 mmbtu = 1 MW\n\nPlease let me know if you can help me or point me to someone who can.  Just \nFYI...Bryan suggested that I call you so blame him as you curse me under your \nbreath right now.\n\nThanks,\nLisa\n\n",
        "filename" : "1045.",
        "headers" : {
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding" : "7bit",
                "Content-Type" : "text/plain; charset=us-ascii",
                "Date" : ISODate("2001-04-05T14:45:00Z"),
                "From" : "eric.bass@enron.com",
                "Message-ID" : "<2106897.1075854772243.JavaMail.evans@thyme>",
                "Mime-Version" : "1.0",
                "Subject" : "Re: Power Generation Question",
                "To" : [
                        "lisa.gillette@enron.com"
                ],
                "X-FileName" : "ebass.nsf",
                "X-Folder" : "\\Eric_Bass_Jun2001\\Notes Folders\\Sent",
                "X-From" : "Eric Bass",
                "X-Origin" : "Bass-E",
                "X-To" : "Lisa Gillette",
                "X-bcc" : "",
                "X-cc" : ""
        },
        "mailbox" : "bass-e",
        "subFolder" : "sent"
}
```

And I need to find records from address X to address Y.

I managed to catch the "From" records with

```
db.messages.find({"headers.From": "eric.bass@enron.com"}).pretty().count()
```

But I can't get the To records (and I Need to get both togheter).

To query the "To" field I've tried:

```
db.messages.find({headers: {$elemMatch :{ "To": "lisa.gillette@enron.com"}}})
```

But it returns nothing

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Did you trydb.messages.find({"headers.To": "lisa.gillette@enron.com", "headers.From": "eric.bass@enron.com"}) ?

Comment: @anhlc That woule be the answer. If you had put a reply I would have marked it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) - To use this operator we need to give the array element and the matching operator, here in your case it should be like

```
db.messages.find({"headers.To": {$elemMatch :{$eq:"lisa.gillette@enron.com"}}})
```

$elemMatch is optimal to use when we have multiple queries to given for the array elements. If we are specifying only a single  condition in the $elemMatch expression, we don't need to use $elemMatch, instead we can use find

```
db.messages.find({"headers.To": "lisa.gillette@enron.com"});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I did like this and it worked:
db.messages.find({"headers.From":"andrew.fastow@enron.com","headers.To":"jeff.skilling@enron.com"})